# how to use proguard in android 2.3

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

one of the features in android 2.3 is integrated proguard obfuscation when doing release builds. but how do i enable this obfuscation when creating my apk?

thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this [site](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)?

Answer (score 4):

add the following into **default.properties**

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

For details visit [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Answer (score 2):

I just used it with maven. If you are using maven as well, I would recommend you reading [this blog post](http://www.simpligility.com/2010/12/proguard-for-android-with-maven-without-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot/).